# CSS not working on smaller page sizes using @media

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a site I made using bootstrap and CSS I have a list that is on the side in a normal sized screen (computer/laptop) When the screen is reduced to mobile less than 500px I want the list to drop to the bottom of the page.

I used the bootstrap class hidden-md-down to remove some divs on page collapse that work great.

**Here is a example on CodePen** *https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qwZxbm* The bottom photo disappears since I use a bootstrap class to remove it on smaller screen sizes. The list needs to drop all the way to the bottom of the page as it does not.

*snippet of the side bar on the page*

```
    <div class="row">
                <!-- Sidebar -->
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="sidebar">


                        <div class="sidebar-section">
                            <h5><span>Post</span></h5>
    <a href="#"><img src="#" title="new" alt=" photo"></a>
                        </div>


<div class="hiddenmobile">
                        <div class="sidebar-section">
                            <h5><span>Latest Blog Posts</span></h5>
                            <?php foreach($posts as $posts):{ ?>
                            <ul style="list-none;">
                                <li><strong><a style="color:lightgreen;" target="_blank" href="<?php echo site_url('/Blog/'.$post['slug']);?>"><?php echo $post['title']; ?></a></strong></li>
                            </ul>
                            <?php }endforeach; ?>
                        </div>
</div>


                        <div class="sidebar-section hidden-md-down">
                            <h5><span>Photo</span></h5>
    <a href="#"><img src="#" title="new Gift Ideas" alt="photo"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS **The @media is what doesnt seem to work as it should drop the div hiddenmobile to the bottom of the page**

```
@media(max-width: 575px) {
  .hiddenmobile{
    display: flex!important;
    flex-direction: column-reverse!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Create an [mcve]

Comment: You need a white space before the exclamation mark of `!important`

Comment: Here is a example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qwZxbm @Adriano no luck

Comment: Your Codepen demo doesn't include a reference to Bootstrap, but you're also using obsolete classes. `hidden-md-down` is no longer used. You'd want something like `d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block`, which is more verbose but I the way it's done now.

Comment: More importantly, your code suggests that you don't understand how flexbox works. What you have in your media query says that element with `hiddenmobile` will be a flexible box (i.e., a container whose contents flex). It's working, but not the way you expect. That element has one direct descendent (a `.sidebar-section` div), but if you added another child, you'd see that they do re-order by the `flex-direction` rule declared. I think this is just an issue of trying the wrong solution, so you should ask about the actual problem rather your attempted solution.

Comment: @denmch I added it to a now include bootstrap https://www.bootply.com/nMjAHSZE9l Edit for your second response, yes I am still new to front end work especially css.

Comment: If you wanted one section of the sidebar to change its order, you could set the whole sidebar to display flex, and then do things with `order`, but that's bad practice and could lead to poor accessibility. Likewise, if you're asking a client to download a media asset, you should at least display it. If you want it to disappear, you probably shouldn't load it on small screens, but then you're getting into a topic that's probably too advanced.

Answer (score 0):

For your media expression to work properly, you need to fix it:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 575px)
```

UPD: but in order for the block to move to the bottom at a certain resolution, there is one of the many options in your case:

```
.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
  /* it is better to replace this class with one that clearly fits your block */
  .hiddenmobile { 
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

Thus, using the `order` property, you set the position of the block you need. If other blocks do not have this property, then the corresponding block goes to the bottom.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and the syntax is not incorrect. Media type is not required as part of the media query.